# Perfview is not stopping

Tags: perfview

I'm running this PerfView command:

`PerfView.exe /Merge:true /zip:true /NoNGenRundown /NoClrRundown /KeepAllEvents /ThreadTime /DumpHeap /NoView /NoGui /MaxCollectSec:30 collect`

but it seems that even if I defined `/MaxCollectSec:30` to 30 seconds the actual data collection process is not stopping and keep adding data to `PerfViewData.etl` file

This is the output from console windows that Perfview open when running command:

> VERBOSE LOG IN: PerfViewData.log.txt
>
> EXECUTING: PerfView /Merge:true /zip:true /NoNGenRundown /NoClrRundown /KeepAllEvents /ThreadTime /DumpHeap /NoView /NoGui /MaxCollectSec:30 collect
>
> Pre V4.0 .NET Rundown disabled, Type 'E' to enable symbols for V3.5 processes.
>
> Do NOT close this console window.   It will leave collection on!
>
> Type S to stop collection, 'A' will abort.
>
> Kernel Log: C:\PerfView\PerfViewData.kernel.etl
>
> User mode Log: C:\PerfView\PerfViewData.etl
>
> Starting collection at 12/07/2017 14:26:32
>
> Collecting   10 sec: Size= 10.5 MB.
>
> Collecting   20 sec: Size= 16.4 MB.
>
> Exceeded MaxCollectSec 30

So here it is: `Exceeded MaxCollectSec 30` but keep writing to etl files.

I want to send to client an Perfview command to collect system wide data and send me back the zip file with all ETL files from Perfview. Currently command does not stop - somebody know why ? What should I add/remove from command so it will stop automatically  after 30 seconds ?

Comment: I always use WPR.exe to capture ETW traces and timeout to set a time: **wpr.exe -start DotNET && timeout 30 && wpr.exe -stop C:\DotNET.etl**. After 30s the stop command is executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been a while, but it looks like the `/DumpHeap` switch is the problem here - if you remove it, the trace will finish on time. I checked the PerfView source code and when DumpHeap is selected there is some interaction with the GUI window:

```cs
if (parsedArgs.DumpHeap)
{
    // Take a heap snapshot.
    GuiHeapSnapshot(parsedArgs, true);

    // Ensure that we clean up the heap snapshot state.
    parsedArgs.DumpHeap = false;

}
```

You may create an issue in [perfview](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) describing your problem.